# How to multiply a value in a textbox by other values in an array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, math, multiplication

My task is to display a total when the user enters a quantity of their choice and multiply it by the price on an individual item.

The individual item price is held in an array of 5 and i am unsure how to multiply the price by a number entered inside a textbox?

Info :
Using Visual Studio, Windows Forms App .Net Framework

I need to display the total price of a car and multiple that by whatever quantity i enter into a different textbox. 
Each vehicle has its own description,promo code and price within the array.
So what i am wondering is do i need to use the price set in the array for my calculation? or is there a much simpler way of doing it?

My attempt was using a simple if statement then multiplying the textbox by the prices set in the array.

```
Convert.To Double(textBox9.Text);    
textBox17.Text = textBox9.Text * prices;
```

Comment: Why does it matter that the value comes from a textbox? `*` is the multiplication operator in C#. I suspect that your question really isn't about multiplication -- but then what *is* it about? How to get a value from a text box? Surely that must be covered in whatever textbook you are reading.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? Web Forms? UWP? WPF? Silverlight? C# is a programming language, not a UI framework. Please [edit] your question to include what UI technology you're using. Also, please show what you've tried and what research you've done to answer this question yourself.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to parse the string coming from the textbox into a number, typically via `Int32.Parse(myTextBox.Text)`. Other than that, I'm not really sure where the problem might be... for future reference, please include a snipped of what you have tried before and where exactly your problem is, otherwise people will find it difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't do string math.** You need to develop a model ( a class ) that does the math for you, and your UI only displays the data.

```
public class CartItem
{
    public decimal Price {get; set; }
    public int Quantity {get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get { return Quantity*Price; } }
}
```

and on your UI you can do things like

```
CartItem item;
// .. fill data
if(int.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out int x))
{
    item.Quantity = x;
}

textBox21.Text = item.Cost.ToString("c");
```